# validation for a field to avoid a dot in it in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a field in my sign up form . I have the reqiurement that my login field should not contain any dot in it

so in my model  i wrote like

**validates_inclusion_of    :login, :in => %w(.), :message => "should not contain dot!"**

Is this correct one ..

The above thing works for me .. 
but i dont know how is it working ...

As per the documentation 's inclusion should check for the characters inside and if not it should reject rite??

But how come its doing in reverse ??

Please give suggestions..

Comment: you accept any other symvbols (all of them: comma, &, ! etc) and excludes only dot?

Comment: what does inclusion means , it should include only that specified characters or it wont .. How come it's rejecting this character and not allowing a dot in login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use something like this:

```
validates_format_of :login,
                    :with => /^[^\.]*$/,
                    :message => "should not contain dot!"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
validates :login, :format => { :with => /[^.]*/ }
```